# javascript implement thousand separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've written a page with ASP.NET MVC. Basically the page allows users to key in some financial data and store them. Simple and easy. Recently my client specifically asked me to put thousand separators on all data fields on the page. I've been thinking about how to make this change for several hours now. Still don't feel I got the perfect plan.

In my mind, the biggest issue would be:

Currently, the model fields are all decimal, the js function that I use to get the values and post them back is simply `myForm.serialize(); $.post(...);` After I add the thousand separators into my fields, apparently I have to do something before I post the values back. Otherwise they won't be translated successfully into decimals with the commas. Maybe removing the commas? But how?

Comment: Do you mean you want commas within the `<input>` elements as the user types? That's very fiddly. Easier to put them in on `blur` and take them out on `focus` so that you don't have to worry about where the cursor is within the number the user is editing.

Comment: You might be interested in [this plugin](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-numericinput)